# Determinant of $5 \times 5$ Boolean matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the set of $5 \times 5$ matrices with $10$ entries equal to $1$ and the other $15$ entries equal to $0$. I would like to know how many such matrices have nonzero determinant. Is there a way to characterize them?

I experimented a little with some examples, but could not make much progress.

Comment: Remember that for a matrix to have nonzero determinant, the rows must be linearly independent.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, but I do not see how that helps.

Comment: It helps eliminate some from the shear number you can write down, but first you should know how many such matrices can be written. The ones with duplicate rows are very easy to enumerate here

Comment: Don't go for large matrices instantly. Start maybe with $3 \times 3$ matrices and maybe $3$ ones and six zeros. Then move to four ones and five zeros, gradually increasing the number of ones. See if you can generalize, then increase the order of the matrix.

Comment: @Triatticus There are $\binom{25}{10}=3 268 760$ such matrices I can write down. Indeed, the determinant of some of these is obviously 0.

Comment: There's a nifty way to count the number of such matrices with an *odd* determinant, but this isn't quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Indeed it's a very large number of arrays

Comment: Up to a permutation of the columns, you can assume that your matrix has $1$s along the main diagonal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks. I think that is true. That is a necessary, but not sufficient condition.

Comment: Matrices of this form have specific entries on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix) and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/01-Matrix.html), and are variously known as "a logical matrix, binary matrix, relation matrix, Boolean matrix, or (0,1) matrix " (Wikipedia). Since having zero determinant means a matrix is singular, this question can be stated concisely as: "How many n-by-n (0,1)-matrices are singular?" Searching under this name brings up an older MO [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/18636/55904), along with OEIS entry [A046747](http://oeis.org/A046747).

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks. My problem is a little different than "How many n-by-n (0,1)-matrices are singular?", though. In my case, the total number of $0$s and of $1$s is fixed. So, I cannot use the result A046747 you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I have examined the $2^9=512$ matrices $3\times 3$. All possible distribution of $0$s and $1$s. The results are summarized in this matrix
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 0 & 36 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & 3 & 78 & 3 & 0 \\
 4 & 0 & 18 & 90 & 18 & 0 \\
 5 & 0 & 36 & 54 & 36 & 0 \\
 6 & 3 & 18 & 42 & 18 & 3 \\
 7 & 0 & 9 & 18 & 9 & 0 \\
 8 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 0 \\
 9 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
In the first column the number of $1$s; in the other $5$ columns the number of matrix having determinant $-2;\;-1;0;\;+1;\;+2$

For instance matrices with $5$ $1$s and $4$ $0$s with determinant $0$ are $54$ while those with determinant $1$ or $-1$ are $36$.

Do you see some regularity?

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I do not see any regularity, but maybe somebody else will.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't scale well, but should run quickly on anything up to $8\times 8$ matrices on modern hardware.

Let $D([k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n])$ return a histogram of the determinants of an $n\times n$ matrix containing $k_1$ $1$'s in its first column, $k_2$ $1$'s in its second column, ..., and $k_n$ $1$'s in its $n$th column. Naturally, there are ${n \choose k_1} {n \choose k_2} \cdots {n \choose k_m}$ such matrices.

For $n = 2$, $$D([0,0]) = \left\{ 0: 1 \right\}$$
$$D([0,1]) = \left\{ 0: 2 \right\}$$
$$D([0,2]) = \left\{ 0: 1 \right\}$$
$$D([1,0]) = \left\{ 0: 2 \right\}$$
$$D([1,1]) = \left\{ -1: 1, 0: 2, 1: 1 \right\}$$
$$D([1,2]) = \left\{ -1: 1, 1: 1 \right\}$$
$$D([2,0]) = \left\{ 0: 1 \right\}$$
$$D([2,1]) = \left\{ -1: 1, 1: 1 \right\}$$
$$D([2,2]) = \left\{ 0: 1 \right\}$$

For each $n$ from $3$ to $n_{\max}$, where $n_{\max}$ is the size of the full matrix (5, in your case):

1. generate all pairs $(k_1,k_2)$ with $0 \leq k_1 \leq n$, $0 \leq k_2 \leq n\left(n-1\right)$ such that $k_1 + k_2 \leq n_1$, where $n_1$ is the number of 1's in the matrix (10 in your case).
2. for each $k_1$, produce $R(n,k_1)$, the set of all $n$-element row vectors containing $k_1$ 1's and $n-k_1$ 0's.
3. for each $k_2$, produce $B(n,k_2)$, the set of all $n$-element row vectors whose elements are non-negative integers that sum to $k_2$.
4. for each $(k_1,k_2)$ pair

   i. for each $r \in R(n,k_1)$ and each $b \in B(n,k_2)$

   1. Let $r$ be the topmost row of a matrix and let $b$ be the number of $1$'s in the columns of the $\left( n-1\right) \times n$ submatrix below the first row. For example, $r = [1,1,0]$, $b = [2,0,1]$ would have a top row of $[1\; 0\; 1]$, two $1$'s in the first column under the first row, zero $1$'s in the second column under the first row, and one $1$ in the third column under the first row.
   2. Suppose you have the matrix $$\left(\begin{array}[c] & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \times & \times & \times \\ \times & \times & \times \end{array}\right)$$ with $b = [2,0,1]$. The histogram of all determinants for matrices of this type is given by $$H = 1\cdot D([0,1]) - 1\cdot D([2,1]) + 0\cdot D([2,0])$$ Since these are histograms, scalar multiplication by $0$ means moving all counts into the $0$ bin, scalar multiplication by $-1$ means negating the bins, and addition is accomplished through convolution. (If somebody knows how to word this better, please edit.)
   3. Add the histogram $H$ from (2) to a list associated with the vector $r+b$. For example, the above $H$ would be added to the list associated with $[3,1,1]$.

   ii. Compute $D(x)$ for all $n$-element vectors $x$ by letting $D(x)$ be the sum (convolution) of all histograms in the list associated with $x$.

The sum of $D(x)$ over all $n_{\max}$-element vectors $x$ yields the determinant histogram for an $n_{\max}\times n_{\max}$ matrix. The number of matrices with zero determinant will be the count in the $0$ bin; the number of matrices with nonzero determinant will be the sum of the counts in the remaining bins. Obviously, the two should sum to $n_{\max}^2 \choose n_1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. When I get the chance, I will try to implement it and will let you know how it went. Thanks again!